# Should I change format and/or add data to image files in a file upload?

Tags: webserver, file-upload, image

I am designing an image upload platform to my website and was thinking about a few recommendations I found online which were NOT outlined in the [OWASP unrestricted file upload list](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unrestricted_File_Upload).

Those security solutions:

1. Changing file format (e.g from .jpeg to .bmp or .png to .bmp etc).
2. Rendering image / compressing it and re-uploading the new file

Are those two solutions useful? If so - why? If I decided to use those techniques, in case of time vs. security, are both solutions worthy?

Comment: who/what do you want to protect?

Comment: just a basic picture upload method, with fundamental security rules taken in mind.

Comment: but, do you want to protect your server or your users?

Comment: both, I guess. on the server side I am thinking on running a scan on each file (ClamAV), and XSS filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By changing format, a malicious user cannot force a certain behaviour by the client. If there is a jpeg vulnerability in a well-known viewer, then by changing the image to png, the malicious actor cannot use that technique.

Re-rendering the image does the same thing. A malicious actor cannot embed malicious code to affect your users.

Changing format and re-rendering should not take much time, but you have to budget your server resources so that you do not run out of resources.

Comment: Thanks! so seems I can chose one of those 2x methods? would you recommend picking one method and not both?

Comment: I would choose the method that has the lesser impact on your server

Answer (score 0):

Any exploit in the file is very unlikjely to survive changing the file format - I would also recommend stripping or sanitizing any metadata in the file. Resampling the file might be slightly less effective (but only marginally so).

**However** the webserver is now actively processing the content and *may* be using the same libraries the exploit targets. i.e. you should think about whether you are shooting yourself in the foot by attempting this; if your server is compromised then the attacker gains control over the content sent back to clients.

It also opens the door to DOS attacks - manipulating images like this requires the file to be converted to a bitmap. I imagine that it would relatively easy to craft a zip-bomb as an image file.

Comment: Why is he unlikely to survive the change?

Comment: because it is highly improbable that (outside of the metadata) any sequence of bytes long enough to effect an exploit (i.e. a program) will not be changed.

Comment: OK thanks, so basically those are my only options against Image_XSS attack?(inserting malicious data to an img file)

Comment: Malicious data as opposed to malicious code? Image XSS uses metadata to house malicious code, it does not provide an exploit. http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/exploit-xss-image/#gref OTOH the image data itself can be an exploit e.g. https://www.symantec.com/security_response/vulnerability.jsp?bid=11173